# Match Made It in Heaven meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

How to understand in other words the title of the text according to the story?:

**Match Made It in Heaven**

As I sat sipping a cup of tea at my sister Doris" house, my husband, Brian,  caught my eye and flashed me a wide smile. Brian"s eyes had lit up when he saw Michael, our nephew, playing with a pile of craft matchsticks, attempting to make a house."How about a challenge?" he said to Michael. "You make a house and I'll make a little boat". In a couple of hours the pair had cut, crafted and glued the matchsticks together and the task was complete. "I'm going to call the boat Hazel," Brian said proudly. That was when his pastime really started.

We found a hobby shop that sold modelling matchsticks, and we soon became their best customers. "I'm going to get bags of them," Brian said. "I'll start a new project when I get home." He got to work on a larger boat, swiftly followed by an  exact copy of a Second World War torpedo boat. Brian was never happier than when he was sat in front of the TV with his matchsticks and PVA glue. It was a great way to keep his mind occupied as he'd retired from his refrigerator factory job years before with health problems, so I was pleased he'd found a hobby he loved.

Soon he decided to build a giant grandmother clock. The project was developing well; it just would have been nice to clear up my living room floor occasionally. Brian would make sections of the clock and then he'd piece it together. It took around seven years and 210,000 matchsticks to complete the grandmother clock. It now has pride of place in our living room, and chimes to the tune of Big Ben every 15 minutes.

As the pieces mounted up, the space in our house disappeared. "We're going to have to find new homes for some of your models," I said to Brian one day. The loft was crammed full of pieces and I hadn't seen the coffee table in years. He"d made a beautiful rocking horse, complete with a saddle made from one of my old bags, which we gave to Brian"s sister. He'd also built a huge windmill that played Tulips from Amsterdam, which we donated to his aunt.

The craziest idea Brian ever had was to row from Dover to Calais in a giant boat made of matchsticks. He actually got as far as constructing the 5ft frame. It took nearly a month and 216,000 matchsticks to build, but thankfully that idea was shelved. Instead, he contented himself with making yet another old wartime boat. There were working lights, tiny lifeboats and even the propellers worked.
But hopefully the latest boat won"t be here for much longer.
"Do you think the maritime museum would accept the boat?" Brian asked recently. "That's a lovely idea," I said. It would be great if they did - then at least I might get my living room back.

Answer (score 4):

A "match" (marriage) "made in heaven" is one between two people who are exceptionally well suited to each other. The title is a play on the multiple meanings of "match" (it is about a marriage in which the husband is obsessed with making models from matches). However, it is severely ungrammatical. Omission of "it" would remedy this. I suspect that the title, if not the text, was composed by a non-native speaker.

Comment: Match Made It Heaven = to get married in a church?

Comment: A church is not "heaven". A "match made **in** heaven" is a marriage of people who are very suited to each other. As I wrote above.

Comment: My friend, I am from Ukraine, so here you can get married in civilian registrar's / registry office with your future wife and after and if you want to marry in heaven (this is a special rite in the church) you go to church and perform this ritual, literally it sounds like "marriage in heaven" (that is, go through this ritual in the church). In English, you only have the word wedding, but this ritual can be literally translated as to go through a service of marriage or to get married in church. Does this phrase (match made in heaven) relate to the ritual in the church or not? Thank you.

Comment: @Jane The phrase "match made in heaven" does not have any necessary connection with a church wedding (at least not these days). It simply means that 2 people or other things are so well matched that they must have been blessed/arranged by a deity. It might be 2 people, a person and a pet, 2 animals, a houseplant and a sunny corner of a room--pretty much any 2 or more things that are very well suited to each other.

Comment: ... and where two people are involved, there need be no implication of romantic or even sexual compatibility. You might say that a company did well because the CEO and the chief accountant were a match made in heaven.

Comment: I don't think that in English, a "match made in heaven" ever meant that the couple were married in a religious ceremony. Many such couples turned (and turn) out to be poorly matched.

Comment: Bacon and eggs, whisky and soda, avocado and lemon juice, are all matches made in heaven for me.

Comment: the first and the second is OK:) and...